# dynamic ssl certificate with nginx

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, devops

I had a Shopify-like application. So, my customer get sub-domain when they create store(i.e `customer1.myShopify.com`).

to handle this case of dynamic sub-domains with nginx:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name admin.myapp.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://admin-front-end:80/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name *.myapp.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app-front-end:80/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

this works great so if you visit `admin.myapp.com` you'll see the admin application and if you visit any `xxx.myapp.com` you'll see the shop-front-end application.

### **The Problem**

I want to allow my customer to connect their own domain. so I told them to connect with `CNAME` and `A Record`.

`A Record` => `@` => `12.12.12.3(my root nginx ip)`

`CNAME` => `WWW` => `thier.myapp.com`

not each request to `customer.com` will resolved by my nginx.

so I added this configuration to my nginx, to catch all other server_name request:

```
server {
        listen  80;
        server_name  server_name ~^.*$;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://app-front-end:80/;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
}
```

and it works fine.

but how can I handle `SSL` for this case? because it could be any domain name.I don't know what the customer domain name will be.

how i can give them the ability to add SSL certificate automatically and without create manually ?

Comment: hey, have you figured it out? I found a third question like this, but unanswered.

Answer (score 12):

This server block should work since variable names are supported for `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` directives.

```
http {

    map "$ssl_server_name" $domain_name { ~(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)$ $2.$3; }

    server {
        listen  443;
        server_name  server_name ~^.*$;

        ssl_certificate /path/to/cert/files/$domain_name.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /path/to/cert/keys/$domain_name.key;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://app-front-end:80/;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    }
}
```

**P.S.** Using variable names would compromise performance because now nginx would load the files on each ssl handshake.

**Ref:** https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate

Comment: Is there a way to quantify the performance penalty of loading the SSL file on each handshake?

Answer (score 0):

In my view instead of compromising the nginx performance, we should use one cron job, say letsencrypt bot, which will fetch certificate based on user requested domain, and you can add the certificate in nginx conf, and restart server.

Bonus:

I have used traefik which is kubernetes based solutions, they load configs on the fly without the restart.

Answer (score 0):

In **VM** you can use the [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) for managing the SSL/TLS certificate.

Now if you are using the `HTTP-01` method to verify your domain you **won't** be able to get the Wild card domain name.

i would suggest to use the `DNS-01` method in cert-bot for domain verification and you can get the **wild card** certificate and use it.

Adding the certificate to Nginx config using :

```
ssl_certificate /path/to/cert/files/tls.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /path/to/cert/keys/tls.key;
```

If you are using the `certbot` it will also auto inject and add the SSL config above lines to the configuration file.

For different domains also you can run the job or certbot with `HTTP-01` method and you will get the certificate.

If you are on Kubernetes you can use the [cert-manager](https://cert-manager.io/docs/), which will be managing the `SSL/TLS` certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using separete block with different ssh certificates thats the only solution that worked for me

```
   server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html/example1.com;
    index index.html;
    server_name example1.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/privkey.pem;
    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
     }
   }

   server {
     listen 80;
     root /var/www/html/example2.com;
     index index.html;
     server_name example2.com;
     ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.com/fullchain.pem;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.com/privkey.pem;
     location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
  }
```